# Sending mails without the user's E-mail/password in Android

Tags: android, webview, jakarta-mail, email

I'm trying to implement a method that can send a mail to my E-mail (always) so that the user only has to write a message and click on "Send". How can this be implemented? Is there a way to do that?

The solution I've thought about is to create an E-mail which is already signed in when the user launches the app, and in that way the user can send a mail from this E-mail to my real E-mail. What do you think? I prefer the first method if it's possible :)

The way I'm handling it now is by using a native app to send a mail, but I want to get around that and send directly from my app.

This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
  public void sendEmail()
    {
        String [] reciever = new String[]{"mymail@hotmail.com"};
        String subject = ("Feedback/Question");
        Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, reciever);
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg.getText());
        mailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Choose an application"));
    }
```

Something else I've thought is to use a `Webview` where the user only has to write a message and click on "Send". Like the most websites do; you write your own E-mail, a topic and the message. However, this solution requires a website, and I don't have that. In addition to that I couldn't find an existing website that could do that for me.

I have read about the mail API, but this API requires that the user has a Gmail and has to write a password.

Comment: Have a look at java mail.

Comment: @greenapps Have already done that, but couldn't find a solution :)

Comment: Then wat is the problem? Java mail would do it.

Comment: `this solution solution requires a website`. But your app would not send a silent email then. Instead it would upload some data to a webserver. The webserver could then send an email.

Comment: It is strange that the things you mention in the subject are not described in your post. So it is difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: @greenapps maybe I've misunderstood you, but I have mentioned that I've read about Java mail and couldn't benefit from you "I have read about the mail API, but this API requires that the user has a Gmail and has to write a password"

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with the user has a Gmail. Anyhow java mail has nothing to do with google or having a gmail email address or account. Or the GMail app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem...  If you do it without a password, people can use it to send spam.  You don't want that.

You can embed your email username and password in your app, but still someone can extract that information from your app and use it to abuse your email account.

The suggested approach from @greenapps is to move the use of email to an app that runs in a server.  Your Android app then contacts the server app, which actually sends the email.  The server app only allows a limited form of email to be sent, and only to your one specific email address.  This means the email username and password is only stored on the server, where it can be better protected.

Of course, this still allows anyone to access the server and ask it to send a message.  They can't do just anything with the server, they can only ask it to send a message to you.  That reduces the attack vector significantly, but there's still potential for abuse.

You might need to provide some sort of password when accessing the server app.  But again, that password will need to be embedded in your Android app, which someone could extract and use to abuse your server app.

You could generate a per-user unique ID when the Android app is installed and use that to track any abuse of your server app.  That doesn't prevent abuse, but allows you to cut off abusers.

You have to decide how much risk you'll willing to accept and how complicated you want this to be in order to reduce the potential for abuse.